# ALSA-Sound: Capture Line-In

Tags: audio, alsa, soundcard, audio-capture, libalsa

I'm using the asoundlib library to read sound (which is playing on my other PC and which I plugged into my  [external sound card](https://www.trust.com/de/product/14134-5-1-external-surround-sound-card)) on my raspberry pi 4, first I tried using the mic input but apparently that shouldn't be used with amplified signals (my reads are distorted as hell), apparently I should use the Line in port.

When I go into my Pi's Audio Device settings, I see that it recognizes the Line In, but I canonly use "hw:1,0" in the alsa lib, all other hardware code "hw:1,1", "hw:1,2", "hw:1,3" yield a "No such file or directory.

Terminal also says that there's only one device (although I'm not really sure what it's trying to tell me):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/C/rpi_ws281x $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution: There is only the "hw:1,0" even if your card has Mic and Line, you have to enter "alsamixer -D hw:1" in the Terminal (where 1 is the card number) and you get the mixer where you can choose whether you want to use Mic or Line